# Fb.ui apprequests show nothing in friend list in ie8

Tags: javascript, facebook

sorry for my bad english..

as far as i know, lots of game apps have the same problem .

friend list works well in ie9/10,ff and chrome, but failed in ie8, no friends displayed,

but if i switch to another option then switch back, then it works!!

i already tried a lot time,so strange @@!! 
var ui_data = {
                    method: 'apprequests',
                    new_style_message: true,
                    message: 'test',
                    filters: ['all', 'app_non_users','app_users']
                };
                FB.ui(ui_data, function (response) { });

Anyone can help!!

Thanks a lot!.